# What is the meaning of a finite transverse extent?

Tags: optics, definition, spectroscopy, photonics

In the book [Terahertz Spectroscopy and Imaging](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-29564-5) it is stated that:

"*We begin by assuming quasi-collimated propagation of a monochromatic and
spatially coherent beam. Such a paraxial beam travels in a well-defined direction and is by definition of finite transverse extent.*"

**What is the meaning of the term finite transverse extent?**

---

I have read on a [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-transverse-extent-of-a-photon-How-close-does-one-have-to-be-to-the-line-of-propagation-of-a-photon-to-interact-with-it-or-absorb-it) page (which shows no sources of information that):

"*The transverse extent is the wavelength of the photon.*"

But this seems to me that, the author of the article in my book could have simply written "of finite wavelength." instead, so why complicate it?

PS: the book is very difficult to find online, if some more contextualization is needed, please tell me so I can upload the full page onto here.

Comment: Transverse is the direction perpendicular to the propagation direction. Therefore _finite transverse extent_ means it's a beam which fits through a large enough hole – in contrast to an infinitely extended plane wave.

Comment: So it simply represents a finite wave oscillate in a direction parallel to its direction of propagation? Like a transverse wave?

Comment: The finite transverse extent doesn't enforce a particular direction of oscillation. You can have a narrow beam of light (transverse wave) as well as a narrow beam of sound (longitudinal wave).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Do please write your answer down for other to see and to get an upvote from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transverse is the direction perpendicular to the propagation direction. Therefore *finite transverse extent* means it's a beam which fits through a large enough hole – in contrast to an infinitely extended plane wave.
It doesn't enforce a particular direction of oscillation. You can have a narrow beam of light (transverse wave) as well as a narrow beam of sound (longitudinal wave).